# Google sign in and Firebase authentication relationship?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

My firebase app's only form of authentication is through Google. When I try to log a user out using `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()`, Firebase still says the user is logged in however. So when I have the following code in my home screen (first screen after a user logged in), "User is logged in..." gets printed out:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
        FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            if let user = user {
                print("User is logged in...")
            else {
                print("User not logged in..."
            }
        }
}
```

In order to properly log a user out do I have to do both the google sign out AND the firebase sign out? I'm unsure why the following code says the user is logged in even though I explicitly logged them out right before through the only form of authentication available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for google sign out :

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
```

for firebase sign out :

```
do {
  try firebaseAuth?.signOut()
} catch let signOutError as NSError {
  print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
}
```

> In order to properly log a user out do I have to do both the google sign out AND the firebase sign out?

yea .. you have to sign out both .Because there no internal connection .. so if you want to logout from firebase call firebase api on the other hand if you want to logout from google then call google api .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to call both the Google sign-out and Firebase sign-out.